# Python Running cumulative sum with a given window

Tags: python, list, numpy, list-comprehension

What I want to do is generate a numpy array that is the cumulative sum of another numpy array given a certain window.

For example, given an array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]` let's say I want a cumulative sum with a window of 3. What I want as out put would be `[1,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33]`. I have a relatively large numpy array and would like to do a cumulative sum with a window of 400.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving average or running mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [42]: lis=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

In [43]: w=3       #window size

In [44]: [sum(lis[i-(w-1):i+1]) if i>(w-1) else sum(lis[:i+1])  for i in range(len(lis))]
Out[44]: [1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33]

In [45]: w=4

In [46]: [sum(lis[i-(w-1):i+1]) if i>(w-1) else sum(lis[:i+1])  for i in range(len(lis))]
Out[46]: [1, 3, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 38, 42]
```

for python 2.4 or less, change the ternary operator:

`(falseValue, trueValue)[condition]` instead of `trueValue if condition else falseValue`

```
[(sum(lis[:i+1]),sum(lis[i-(w-1):i+1]))[i>(w-1)]  for i in range(len(lis))]
```

Comment: @user1440194: you shouldn't be using Python 2.4 anymore. It's ancient. Even 2.5 has reached end of life and is no longer getting security updates.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary, Shouldn't you better use `itertools.accumlate()`?

Comment: @larsvegas `accumulate()` is introduced in python 3.2, I am on python 2.6 and OP is using python 2.4.

Comment: @user1440194 can you post the traceback of `syntaxError` you're getting?

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary, Well, he is using `NumPy` so `numpy.cumsum()` is the way to go. Or just define your cumsum function.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary `File "<ipython console>", line 1
     windowedcumOFI = [sum(OFIs[i-(w-1):i+1]) if i>(w-1) else sum(OFIs[:i+1] for i in range(len(OFIs))]
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` thanks though I just did a normal loop instead of a list comprehension and it worked. The error occurs at the if

Comment: It is called a `list comprehension`.

Comment: @user1440194 the problem is with the ternary operator, python 2.4 supports different type of ternary operator.
http://www.evanfosmark.com/2008/06/ternary-operator-in-python-people-got-clever/

Comment: You could probably do something like this with a combination of convolve and cumsum also.

Comment: I think `[sum(lis[max(0,i-w+1):i+1]) for i in range(len(lis))]` is a bit neater than using that ternary construct.

Answer (score 34):

Here is perhaps a simpler answer, based on subtracting shifted cumsums.

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
>>> b = a.cumsum()
>>> b[3:] = b[3:] - b[:-3]
>>> b
array([ 1,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33])
```

Comment: For others who may read these answers: This is the canonical way to do this in numpy, for whatever it's worth.  If speed matters, it's _much_ faster than any of the other solutions.  You're fundamentally doing many fewer calculations that explicitly re-calculating sum for each window.

Comment: I looked for HOURS for a solution like this... Other answers on Stack Overflow are much higher rated, but this is MUCH faster. Indeed, the canonical numpy way (it even wraps around the original array!). Kudos to you, sir.

Comment: The third line: what if I write `b[3:] = b[3:] - b[:-3]`? Any reason for using `a.cumsum()[:-3]` instead of `b[:-3]`?

Comment: @FrozenFlame, you're right, as far as I can see, `b[3:] = b[3:] - b[:-3]` works fine.  However, watch out, `b[3:] -= b[:-3]` does not work as it modifies elements before they are read.

Answer (score 8):

You should likely use numpy, unless you really don't care about speed (though I would prefere it anyways). So you could use convolve or `stride_tricks` based approaches (these are not obvious, but solve these things nicely).

For example given a function like this (you can find more and fancier versions too):

```
def embed(array, dim, lag=1):
    """Create an embedding of array given a resulting dimension and lag.
    The array will be raveled before embedding.
    """
    array = np.asarray(array)
    array = array.ravel()
    new = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(array,
                                     (len(array)-dim*lag+lag, dim),
                                     (array.strides[0], array.strides[0]*lag))
    return new
```

You can do:

```
embedded = embed(array, 400)
result = embedded.sum(1)
```

Which is memory efficient (the embedding or whatever you call it, does only create a view) and fast. The other approach of course would be to use convolve:

```
np.convolve(array, np.ones(400), mode='valid')
```

I don't know if you want the non full windows too, this would be the same as using `mode='full'` (default) for the convolve. For the other approach, that would have to be handled some other way.

Answer (score 1):

[seberg's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12713297/1015178) answer is better and more general than mine, but note that you need to zero-pad your samples to get the result you want.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as ast
samples = 100
window = 3
padding = np.zeros(window - 1)
# zero-pad your samples
a = np.concatenate([padding,np.arange(1,samples + 1)])
newshape = (len(a) - window,window)
newstrides = a.strides * 2
# this gets you a sliding window of size 3, with a step of 1
strided = ast(a,shape = newshape,strides = newstrides)
# get your moving sum
strided.sum(1)
```