# How to add a line of best fit to scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, linear-regression

I'm currently working with Pandas and matplotlib to perform some data visualization and I want to add a line of best fit to my scatter plot.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as panda
import numpy as np

def PCA_scatter(filename):

   matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

   data = panda.read_csv(filename)
   data_reduced = data[['2005', '2015']]

   data_reduced.plot(kind='scatter', x='2005', y='2015')
   plt.show()

PCA_scatter('file.csv')
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code for best fit straight line of a scatter plot in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239691/code-for-best-fit-straight-line-of-a-scatter-plot-in-python)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

- You can do the whole fit and plot in one fell swoop with the figure-level function [`seaborn.lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html#seaborn.lmplot), or the axes-level function [`seaborn.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html#seaborn.regplot)

  - [Figure-level vs. axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions)
- [seaborn](/questions/tagged/seaborn) is a high-level API for [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib).

  - [It's a plotting API, not a stats packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22852265/7758804). If the values are required, see [How to get the numerical fitting results when plotting a regression in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22852244/7758804).

```py
import seaborn as sns

# sample data
penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')

# plot 1 with axes level-plot
ax = sns.regplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm")

# plot 2 corresponding figure-level plot
g = sns.lmplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm")

# plot 3 figure-level plot separated by species
g = sns.lmplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")
```

#### Plot 1

[image]

#### Plot 2

[image]

#### Plot 3

[image]

Answer (score 17):

You can use `np.polyfit()` and `np.poly1d()`. Estimate a first degree polynomial using the same `x` values, and add to the `ax` object created by the `.scatter()` plot. Using an example:

```
import numpy as np

     2005   2015
0   18882  21979
1    1161   1044
2     482    558
3    2105   2471
4     427   1467
5    2688   2964
6    1806   1865
7     711    738
8     928   1096
9    1084   1309
10    854    901
11    827   1210
12   5034   6253
```

Estimate first-degree polynomial:

```
z = np.polyfit(x=df.loc[:, 2005], y=df.loc[:, 2015], deg=1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
df['trendline'] = p(df.loc[:, 2005])

     2005   2015     trendline
0   18882  21979  21989.829486
1    1161   1044   1418.214712
2     482    558    629.990208
3    2105   2471   2514.067336
4     427   1467    566.142863
5    2688   2964   3190.849200
6    1806   1865   2166.969948
7     711    738    895.827339
8     928   1096   1147.734139
9    1084   1309   1328.828428
10    854    901   1061.830437
11    827   1210   1030.487195
12   5034   6253   5914.228708
```

and plot:

```
ax = df.plot.scatter(x=2005, y=2015)
df.set_index(2005, inplace=True)
df.trendline.sort_index(ascending=False).plot(ax=ax)
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
```

To get:

[image]

Also provides the the line equation:

```
'y={0:.2f} x + {1:.2f}'.format(z[0],z[1])

y=1.16 x + 70.46
```

Comment: the line `trendline.plot(ax=ax)` gives me an invalid syntax error

Comment: the line `z = np.polyfit(x=data_reduced[['2005']], y=data_reduced[['2015']], 1)` gives me a "positional argument follows keyword argument" error

Comment: sorry, need to add `deg` for `degree` before `=1`, see update.

Comment: TypeError: expected 1D vector for x for the line `z = np.polyfit(x=data_reduced[['2005']], y=data_reduced[['2015']], deg=1)`. is this a problem with my data or the code?

Comment: Needed to use `.loc[]` so single column becomes a `pd.Series`. Selecting with `[[]]` keeps a single column as `DataFrame`, hence the dimension warning. Updated, same applies to next line. My bad, it's getting late...

Comment: This is working well now except it's reversed the direction of the data... http://i.imgur.com/k2Wy9in.jpg

Comment: Ok, there's `.sort_values(ascending=True/False)` at the appropriate spot for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111960/discussion-between-pythonnewb-and-stefan-jansen).

Comment: I found that making the trendline using the two points from `ax=get_xlim()` keeps the nice default padding around the scatter points.

Answer (score 5):

Another option (using [`np.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)):

```
# generate some fake data
N = 50
x = np.random.randn(N, 1)
y = x*2.2 + np.random.randn(N, 1)*0.4 - 1.8
plt.axhline(0, color='r', zorder=-1)
plt.axvline(0, color='r', zorder=-1)
plt.scatter(x, y)

# fit least-squares with an intercept
w = np.linalg.lstsq(np.hstack((x, np.ones((N,1)))), y)[0]
xx = np.linspace(*plt.gca().get_xlim()).T

# plot best-fit line
plt.plot(xx, w[0]*xx + w[1], '-k')
```

[image: best-fit line]

Answer (score 2):

This is covering the `plotly` approach

```
#load the libraries

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# create the data
N = 50
x = pd.Series(np.random.randn(N))
y = x*2.2 - 1.8

# plot the data as a scatter plot
fig = px.scatter(x=x, y=y) 

# fit a linear model 
m, c = fit_line(x = x, 
                y = y)

# add the linear fit on top
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=m*x + c,
        mode="lines",
        line=go.scatter.Line(color="red"),
        showlegend=False)
)
# optionally you can show the slop and the intercept 
mid_point = x.mean()

fig.update_layout(
    showlegend=False,
    annotations=[
        go.layout.Annotation(
            x=mid_point,
            y=m*mid_point + c,
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            text=str(round(m, 2))+'x+'+str(round(c, 2)) ,
        )
    ]
)
fig.show()
```

where `fit_line` is

```
def fit_line(x, y):
    # given one dimensional x and y vectors - return x and y for fitting a line on top of the regression
    # inspired by the numpy manual - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html 
    x = x.to_numpy() # convert into numpy arrays
    y = y.to_numpy() # convert into numpy arrays

    A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T # sent the design matrix using the intercepts
    m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=None)[0]

    return m, c
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Best answer above is using seaborn.
To add to above, if you are creating many plots with a loop, you can still use matplotlib

```
    import pandas as pd
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    data_reduced= pd.read_csv('fake.txt',sep='\s+')
    for x in data_reduced.columns:
        sns.regplot(data_reduced[x],data_reduced['2015'])
        plt.show()
```

plt.show() will pause execution so you can view the plots one at a time