# Calculate average values from an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, mean

I have an array with 8760 values. I want to calculate the average for every 24 values and return the 365 average values as an array. Is this correct or is there a more simple way of doing this?

```
temps = data['temperature'] #Fetching temperaturedata from dictionary
temps_array = np.asarray(temps) #Converting temps list to array
averages = daily_mean_temp(temps_array) #Running function that calculates mean



def daily_mean_temp(hourly_temp):
average_temps = [x.mean() for x in np.array_split(
    [float(x) for x in hourly_temp], 365)] #This is a list
average_temps_array = np.asarray(average_temps) #Converting from list to array
return average_temps_array #return array with mean values
```

Comment: What's wrong with `sum(mylist)/len(mylist)` for computing the average of a list?

Comment: @Emmet: I think this is a bit more complex.

Comment: Good answers on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean

Comment: You should update your previous question instead of asking it again.

Comment: "Is this correct" - does it give the answer you were expecting?

Comment: njzk2's solution seemed to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 24 values for each day. Therefore, you can do something like:

```
average_temps_array = [sum(map(float, hourly_temp[i:i+24])) / 24 
                                 for i in range(0, len(hourly_temp), 24)]
```