# Produce random wavefunction

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to produce a random curve in matplotlib.

My x values are from say 1 to 1000 for example. I don't want to generate scattered random y values, I need a smooth curve. Like some kind of very distorted sin curve with varying amplitude and wavelength.

Does something already exist to allow me to easily do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 10)

def f(x):
    return np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(x))

pl.plot(x, f(x))
```

It will give you a sin wave with some noise added to it:

[image: sin wave with noise]

**Edit:**

It seems like some kind of [random walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#Gaussian_random_walk) is what you're looking for. This function will do that for you:

```
def f(x):
    y = 0
    result = []
    for _ in x:
        result.append(y)
        y += np.random.normal(scale=1)
    return np.array(result)
```

This is an example of what it can look like (with `x = np.linspace(0, 1000, 1000)`):

[image: random walk]

It's not a function of `x` any longer though, so the code should probably be refactored to generate a random walk with `n` steps instead. I'll leave that to you :)

**Edit 2:**

If you want a smoother curve, you can apply a running mean ([stolen from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13732668/98057)):

```
def runningMean(x, N):
    return np.convolve(x, np.ones((N,))/N)[(N-1):]

pl.plot(x, runningMean(f(x), 10))
```

The bigger window (the `N` parameter) you use, the smoother the result.

Example:

[image: random walk with running mean]

Comment: Hi thank you. That's not quite what I'm looking for. The underlying sin wave needs to vary much more. I'm thinking more like a stock market trend. The blue or green line here: http://www.crestmontresearch.com/docs/Inflation-PE-FAQ-640x427.jpg

Comment: I added a different function now, a sort of random walk.

Comment: Okay that's great thank you. Is there a way that I can make it smoother?

Comment: Yes, with a running mean for example (updated answer).