# Scikit-Learn Training with Moving Average Values Possible?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a question regarding scikit-learn. I would like to know if it is possible to tell scikit-learn to use `moving average values` as my label values?
I have historic data like: `team1,team2, run_distance1, run_distance2` and would like to use the mean of the last 3 `run_distance1` as the current value. Does sci-kit have this kind of feature?

The idea behind this is to predict the current match of `team1` and `team2` by using the historic data trained on `moving average values (mean)` of the last 3 or X games.

Thank you very much!

Comment: But what is the problem with just adding new feature to original dataset, naming it mean3_run_distance1, and populating with mean value of last 3 run_distance1? After that just feed the dataset to any regression algorithm  you want.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know if there are like some built-in functions except from mean.

Comment: Well, I believe there are tools which could just transform your original data to moving average data. You could use a small function in one of responses here (the one based on convolve is rather fast): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean. Then use the transformed data as regression input - it will also work nicely.