# pd.rolling_mean becoming deprecated - alternatives for ndarrays

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, mean

EDIT: This question was asked in 2016 and similar questions have been posted on SO years later after the functionality was finally removed, e.g. [module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_mean'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482884/module-pandas-has-no-attribute-rolling-mean)

However, the question concerns performance of the new `pd.rolling.mean()` and should stay open until the associated pandas [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12732) is fixed.

---

It looks like `pd.rolling_mean` is becoming deprecated for `ndarrays`,

> ```
>  pd.rolling_mean(x, window=2, center=False)
> ```
>
> FutureWarning: pd.rolling_mean is deprecated for ndarrays and will be removed in a future version

but it seems to be the fastest way of doing this, according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean).

Are there now new ways of doing this directly with SciPy or NumPy that are as fast as `pd.rolling_mean`?

Comment: I still don't see an answer to the question "What is an alternative rolling_mean function for ndarrays?" This should be included in scipy or numpy without needing to rely on a Pandas function intended for use on Dataframes

Answer (score 10):

EDIT -- Unfortunately, it looks like the new way is not nearly as fast:

New version of Pandas:

```
In [1]: x = np.random.uniform(size=100)

In [2]: %timeit pd.rolling_mean(x, window=2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 240 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit pd.Series(x).rolling(window=2).mean()
1000 loops, best of 3: 226 µs per loop

In [4]: pd.__version__
Out[4]: '0.18.0'
```

Old version:

```
In [1]: x = np.random.uniform(size=100)

In [2]: %timeit pd.rolling_mean(x,window=2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.4 µs per loop

In [3]: pd.__version__
Out[3]: u'0.17.1'
```

Comment: good point and it looks like you're right. See my edit. I'm going to open the question up again to see if anyone else has a solution here that retains the older speed.

Comment: dang yeah that sucks !

Comment: See here: this *should* only add a tiny bit of function call overhead, but this has an uncessary copy of the internal blocks, easy fix: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12732

Comment: This is horrible syntax... we went from simple and terse, to something verbose and unpythonic.

Comment: I almost agree - but the new syntax means that we can apply *any* function to that window, not just the precanned ones.

Comment: How can I use pd.series(x), for 3D array. Here x is 3D numpy array.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the new way is via methods on the `DataFrame.rolling` class (I guess you're meant to think of it sort of like a `groupby`):
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/whatsnew.html

e.g.

```
x.rolling(window=2).mean()
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. Should've included this in the question. In any case, it turns out it's just as fast even though it requires explicitly turning `x` into a `pd.Series` first (See my answer with details).

Comment: How can I use pd.series(x), for 3D array. Here x is 3D numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
x.rolling(window=2, center=False).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter1d.html) like in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43200476/1116842) to the linked question. It is also way faster for large arrays:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import uniform_filter1d
N = 1000
x = np.random.random(100000)

%timeit pd.rolling_mean(x, window=N)
__main__:257: FutureWarning: pd.rolling_mean is deprecated for ndarrays and will be removed in a future version
The slowest run took 84.55 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1 loop, best of 3: 7.37 ms per loop

%timeit uniform_filter1d(x, size=N)
10000 loops, best of 3: 190 µs per loop
```

Comment: How can I use pd.series(x), for 3D array. Here x is 3D numpy array.

Answer (score -2):

If your dimensions are homogeneous, you could try to implement an n-dimensional form of the [Summed Area Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table) used for bidimensional images:

> A summed area table is a data structure and algorithm for quickly and efficiently generating the sum of values in a rectangular subset of a grid.

Then, in this order, you could:

1. Create the summed area table ("integral") of your array;
2. Iterate to get the (quite cheap) sum of a n-dimensional kernel at a given position;
3. Divide by the size of the n-dimensional volume of the kernel.

Unfortunately I cannot know if this is efficient or not, but the by the given premise, it should be.

Comment: How can I use pd.series(x), for 3D array. Here x is 3D numpy array.