# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_mean'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to build a ARIMA for anomaly detection. I need to find the moving average of the time series graph I am trying to use pandas 0.23 for this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 15, 6

dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%Y-%m')
data = pd.read_csv('AirPassengers.csv', parse_dates=['Month'], index_col='Month',date_parser=dateparse)

data.index
ts = data['#Passengers']
ts.head(10)

plt.plot(ts)
ts_log = np.log(ts)
plt.plot(ts_log)
moving_avg = pd.rolling_mean(ts_log,12)  # here is the error

pd.rolling_mean  
plt.plot(ts_log)
plt.plot(moving_avg, color='red')
```

> error:Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lastmainprogram.py", line 74, in 
>       moving_avg = pd.rolling_mean(ts_log,12) AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_mean'

Comment: This command is deprecated since 0.18, I think. Use the rolling operation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I believe need change:

```
moving_avg = pd.rolling_mean(ts_log,12)
```

to:

```
moving_avg = ts_log.rolling(12).mean()
```

because old pandas version code below [`pandas 0.18.0`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.18.0.html#window-functions-are-now-methods)

Comment: moving_avg = timeseries["#Passengers"].rolling(window=12).mean() 

here the dataframe timeseries has index as date, and column name #Passengers has the count for passengers in corresponding dates

Answer (score 14):

Change:

```
moving_avg = pd.rolling_mean(ts_log,12)
```

to:

```
rolmean = pd.Series(timeseries).rolling(window=12).mean()

rolstd = pd.Series(timeseries).rolling(window=12).std()
```

Comment: What is 'timeseries' in your second block? Do you mean 'ts_log'?

Answer (score 0):

You will need this in your detection so you can add.

```
moving_std = ts_log.rolling(12).std()
```