# Time Series Python

Tags: python, pandas

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

def test_stationarity(timeseries):
    #Determinacion de variable estadistica
    rolmean = pd.rolling_mean(timeseries, window=12)
    rolstd = pd.rolling_std(timeseries, window=12)
    orig = plt.plot(timeseries, color='blue',label='Original')
    mean = plt.plot(rolmean, color='red', label='Rolling Mean')
    std = plt.plot(rolstd, color='black', label = 'Rolling Std')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.title('Rolling Mean & Standard Deviation')
    plt.show(block=False)
    #Perform Dickey-Fuller test:
    print ('Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:')
    dftest = adfuller(timeseries, autolag='AIC')
    dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4], index=['Test Statistic','p-value','#Lags Used','Number of Observations Used'])
    for key,value in dftest[4].items():
        dfoutput['Critical Value (%s)'%key] = value
        print (dfoutput)

test_stationarity(ts)
```

and the i have this error

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_mean'

could you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling\_mean'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482884/module-pandas-has-no-attribute-rolling-mean)

Comment: [rolling_mean](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) is for dataframes.

Comment: so, i would be put rolmean = pd.rolling_mean(df, window=12)

Comment: Yeah, i import that

Comment: then, when y put df, the following error: AttributeError: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'rolling_std'