# need help keep getting object 'module' has no attribute 'rolling_mean'

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
for ma in ma_day:
    column_name = "MA for %s days" %(str(ma))
    AAPL[column_name] = pd.rolling_mean(AAPL['Adj Close'],ma)
```

I'm getting this error:

> 'module' object has no attribute 'rolling_mean'

I am working with python2

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, you have left out the context of your code snippet. What exactly does `pd` refer to--the `pandas` module? Are you sure that is what it really means? Please provide a complete section of code, one that runs and shows your problem. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.rolling_mean` is deprecated now, there's no such method, which gives an error (also, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274447/pd-rolling-mean-becoming-deprecated-alternatives-for-ndarrays)). There's no such method in actual pandas distributions. Instead you can use a combination of [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) and `mean` methods:

```
for ma in ma_day:
    column_name = "MA for %s days" %(str(ma))
    AAPL[column_name] = AAPL['Adj Close'].rolling(window=ma).mean()
```

Also you can install and use pandas versions `≤ 0.17`, but it's deprecated and highly discouraged.