# Is this an efficient way to compute a moving average?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, moving-average

I've some `{open|high|low|close}` market data. I want to compute a Simple Moving Average from the `close` value of each row.

I've had a look around and couldn't find a simple way to do this. I've computed it via the below method. I want to know if there is a better way:

```
data = get_data_period_symbol('1h', 'EURUSD')

empty_list = np.zeros(len(data))

data['SMA10'] = empty_list
ma = 10

for i in range(ma-1, len(data)):
    vals = data['<CLOSE>'][i-(ma-1):i+1].tolist()
    mean = np.average(vals)
    index = data.index[i]
    data.set_value(index, 'SMA10', mean)
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)?

Comment: See this SO [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean) for efficient rolling mean solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data['SMA10'] = pd.rolling_mean(data['<CLOSE>'][:], 10)
```

Was my original found solution, however you get a warning saying it's deprecated

Therefore:

```
data['SMA10'] = data['<CLOSE>'][:].rolling(window=10, center=False).mean()
```

Answer (score 4):

Pandas provides all the tools you'll need for this kind of thing. 
Assuming you have your data indexed by time:

```
data['SMA10'] = data['<close>'].rolling(window=10).mean()
```

Voila.

Edit:
I suppose just note the newer api usage. Quoting from the [Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#rolling-windows):

> Warning Prior to version 0.18.0, pd.rolling_*, pd.expanding_*, and pd.ewm* were module level functions and are now deprecated. These are replaced by using the Rolling, Expanding and EWM. objects and a corresponding method call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22621523/6614295). So something like this should work:

```
data.loc[ma-1:, "SMA10"] = np.convolve(data["<CLOSE>"], np.ones((ma,))/ma, mode="valid")
```

PS:
I just saw your own answer, which is actually a much nicer solution!