# MATLAB's smooth implementation (n-point moving average) in NumPy/Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, smoothing

Matlab's `smooth` function, by default, smooths data using a 5-point moving average. What would be the best way to do the same in python?
For example, if this is my data

```
0
0.823529411764706
0.852941176470588
0.705882352941177
0.705882352941177
0.676470588235294
0.676470588235294
0.500000000000000
0.558823529411765
0.647058823529412
0.705882352941177
0.705882352941177
0.617647058823529
0.705882352941177
0.735294117647059
0.735294117647059
0.588235294117647
0.588235294117647
1
0.647058823529412
0.705882352941177
0.764705882352941
0.823529411764706
0.647058823529412
0.735294117647059
0.794117647058824
0.794117647058824
0.705882352941177
0.676470588235294
0.794117647058824
0.852941176470588
0.735294117647059
0.647058823529412
0.647058823529412
0.676470588235294
0.676470588235294
0.529411764705882
0.676470588235294
0.794117647058824
0.882352941176471
0.735294117647059
0.852941176470588
0.823529411764706
0.764705882352941
0.558823529411765
0.588235294117647
0.617647058823529
0.647058823529412
0.588235294117647
0.617647058823529
0.647058823529412
0.794117647058824
0.823529411764706
0.647058823529412
0.617647058823529
0.647058823529412
0.676470588235294
0.764705882352941
0.676470588235294
0.647058823529412
0.705882352941177
0.764705882352941
0.705882352941177
0.500000000000000
0.529411764705882
0.529411764705882
0.647058823529412
0.676470588235294
0.588235294117647
0.735294117647059
0.794117647058824
0.852941176470588
0.764705882352941
```

the smoothed data should be

```
0
0.558823529411765
0.617647058823530
0.752941176470588
0.723529411764706
0.652941176470588
0.623529411764706
0.611764705882353
0.617647058823530
0.623529411764706
0.647058823529412
0.676470588235294
0.694117647058824
0.700000000000000
0.676470588235294
0.670588235294118
0.729411764705882
0.711764705882353
0.705882352941177
0.741176470588235
0.788235294117647
0.717647058823529
0.735294117647059
0.752941176470588
0.758823529411765
0.735294117647059
0.741176470588235
0.752941176470588
0.764705882352941
0.752941176470588
0.741176470588235
0.735294117647059
0.711764705882353
0.676470588235294
0.635294117647059
0.641176470588236
0.670588235294118
0.711764705882353
0.723529411764706
0.788235294117647
0.817647058823530
0.811764705882353
0.747058823529412
0.717647058823530
0.670588235294118
0.635294117647059
0.600000000000000
0.611764705882353
0.623529411764706
0.658823529411765
0.694117647058824
0.705882352941176
0.705882352941176
0.705882352941176
0.682352941176471
0.670588235294118
0.676470588235294
0.682352941176471
0.694117647058824
0.711764705882353
0.700000000000000
0.664705882352941
0.641176470588236
0.605882352941177
0.582352941176471
0.576470588235294
0.594117647058824
0.635294117647059
0.688235294117647
0.729411764705882
0.747058823529412
0.803921568627451
0.764705882352941
```

The syntax in Matlab to get this is

```
smooth(data)
```

I want to do the same in python but I am unable to find any function that would do this.

Comment: Is this question the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean?

Comment: @BillBell I don't think so

Comment: here are some other examples: http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/SignalSmooth.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MATLAB's [`smoooth func`](https://in.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html) is basically same as averaging across sliding windows of length `5`, except the way it treats the 2 elems at either ends. As per the linked docs, those boundary cases are computed with these formulae -

> ```
> yy = smooth(y) smooths the data in the column vector y ..
> The first few elements of yy are given by
>
> yy(1) = y(1)
> yy(2) = (y(1) + y(2) + y(3))/3
> yy(3) = (y(1) + y(2) + y(3) + y(4) + y(5))/5
> yy(4) = (y(2) + y(3) + y(4) + y(5) + y(6))/5
> ...
> ```

So, to replicate the same implementation on NumPy/Python, we can use [`NumPy's 1D convolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) for getting sliding windowed summations and divide them by the window length to give us the average results. Then, simply append the special case treated values for the boundary elems.

Thus, we would have an implementation to handle generic window sizes, like so -

```
def smooth(a,WSZ):
    # a: NumPy 1-D array containing the data to be smoothed
    # WSZ: smoothing window size needs, which must be odd number,
    # as in the original MATLAB implementation
    out0 = np.convolve(a,np.ones(WSZ,dtype=int),'valid')/WSZ    
    r = np.arange(1,WSZ-1,2)
    start = np.cumsum(a[:WSZ-1])[::2]/r
    stop = (np.cumsum(a[:-WSZ:-1])[::2]/r)[::-1]
    return np.concatenate((  start , out0, stop  ))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Divakar. But I get the following error when I try to use the function 'smooth': 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cumsum''

Comment: @rsnaveen I was assuming `a` to be a NumPy array. Fixed it to handle both arrays and lists.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Divakar.

Comment: If I copy and past your solution and run it over a numpy array I get     start = np.cumsum(a[:WSZ-1])[::2]/r

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (150,) (149,)

Comment: My array shape was (1436L,), while WSZ=300

Comment: @ErroriSalvo It needs an odd window size, as documented in [MATLAB's smooth docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html). It says there - `"yy = smooth(y,span) sets the span of the moving average to span. span must be odd."`. So, use an odd number for WSZ there.

Comment: ok, I have understood the reason, maybe it is worth mentioning in the answer