# Moving average produces array of different length?

Tags: python, numpy

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13728392/5553319) has a lot of useful answers on how to get a moving average.
I have tried the two methods of numpy convolution and numpy cumsum and both worked fine on an example dataset, but produced a shorter array on my real data.

The data are spaced by `0.01`. The example dataset has a length of `50`, the real data tens of thousands. So it must be something about the window size that is causing the problem and I don't quite understand what is going on in the functions.

This is how I define the functions:

```
def smoothMAcum(depth,temp, scale): # Moving average by cumsum, scale = window size in m
    dz = np.diff(depth)  
    N = int(scale/dz[0])
    cumsum = np.cumsum(np.insert(temp, 0, 0)) 
    smoothed=(cumsum[N:] - cumsum[:-N]) / N 
    return smoothed

def smoothMAconv(depth,temp, scale): # Moving average by numpy convolution
    dz = np.diff(depth) 
    N = int(scale/dz[0])
    smoothed=np.convolve(temp, np.ones((N,))/N, mode='valid') 
    return smoothed
```

Then I implement it:

```
scale = 5.
smooth = smoothMAconv(dep,data, scale)
```

but `print len(dep), len(smooth)`
returns `81071 80572`

and the same happens if I use the other function.
How can I get the smooth array of the same length as the data?

And why did it work on the small dataset? Even if I try different scales (and use the same for the example and for the data), the result in the example has the same length as the original data, but not in the real application. 
I considered an effect of `nan` values, but if I have a `nan` in the example, it doesn't make a difference.

So where is the problem, if possible to tell without the full dataset?

Comment: It is possible include a reproducible example with a data set of large size, by simulated data (such as a random array in my answer).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The second of your approaches is easy to modify to preserve the length, because [`numpy.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html#numpy.convolve) supports the parameter `mode='same'`.

```
np.convolve(temp, np.ones((N,))/N, mode='same')
```

This is made possible by zero-padding the data set `temp` on both sides, -
 which will inevitably have some effect at the boundaries unless your data happens to be 0 near the boundaries. Example:

```
N = 10
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
y = x**2 + np.random.uniform(size=x.shape)
y_smooth = np.convolve(y, np.ones((N,))/N, mode='same') 
plt.plot(x, y, 'r.')
plt.plot(x, y_smooth)
plt.show()
```

[image: smoothing]

The boundary effect of zero-padding is very visible at the right end, where the data points are about 4-5 but are padded by 0.

To reduce this undesired effect, use [`numpy.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) for more intelligent padding; reverting to `mode='valid'` for convolution. The pad width must be such that in total N-1 elements are added, where N is the size of moving window.

```
y_padded = np.pad(y, (N//2, N-1-N//2), mode='edge')
y_smooth = np.convolve(y_padded, np.ones((N,))/N, mode='valid')
```

[image: padding]

Padding by edge values of an array looks much better.