# Plot moving average with data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to calculate and plot moving average along with the data it is calculated from:

```
def movingAvg(df):
window_size = 7
i = 0

moving_averages = []

while i < len(df) - window_size + 1:
    current_window = df[i : i + window_size]
    window_average = current_window.mean()
    moving_averages.append(window_average)
    i += 1

return moving_averages

    
dates = df_valid['dateTime']
startDay = dates.iloc[0]
lastDay = dates.iloc[-1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
ax.autoscale()
#plt.xlim(startDay, lastDay)

df_valid.sedentaryActivityMins.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_moving = pd.DataFrame(movingAvg(df_valid['sedentaryActivityMins']))

df_nan = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
df_nan = pd.DataFrame(df_nan)

df_moving = pd.concat([df_nan, df_moving])
plt.plot(df_valid.sedentaryActivityMins)
plt.plot(df_moving)

#plt.show()
```

But as the moving average uses 7 windows, the list of moving averages is 7 items short, and therefore the plots do not follow each other correctly.

I tried putting 7 "NaN" into the moving average list, but those are ignored when I plot.

The plot is as follows: [image: here]

But I would like the the orange line to start 7 steps ahead.
So it looks like this:
[image]

```
df_valid.sedentaryActivityMins.head(40)
0     608
1     494
2     579
3     586
4     404
5     750
6     573
7     466
8     389
9     604
10    351
11    553
12    768
13    572
14    616
15    522
16    675
17    607
18    229
19    529
20    746
21    646
22    625
23    590
24    572
25    462
26    708
27    662
28    649
29    626
30    485
31    509
32    561
33    664
34    517
35    587
36    602
37    601
38    495
39    352
Name: sedentaryActivityMins, dtype: int64
```

Any ideas as to how?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: NaNs cannot be shown in plot. You can either make the first seven values as zero or assign it to the series itself inorder to ger them plotted

Comment: Hi! If I assign them to 0, the plot looks really funky. How do I assign it to the series?

Comment: I'd recommend using a dynamic window. Until the 7th point, the window size should increase gradually from 1 to 7 and stay constant after that.

Comment: What do you expect those values to be?

Comment: I expect the first 7 to not be shown, otherwise the two plots follow each other incorrectly

Comment: Can you add some data to your question? Please read [mre].

Comment: Related: [Moving average produces array of different length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484899/moving-average-produces-array-of-different-length),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a concat, the indexes don't change. The NaNs will also take the same indices as the first 7 observations of your series. So either do a reset index after the concat or set ignore_index as True as follows:

```
df_moving = pd.concat([df_nan, df_moving],ignore_index=True)
plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(df_moving)
```

This gives the output as expected:

[image]

Comment: Random, but it's funny that you use both "indexes" and "indices" as the plural of Index.

Comment: Haha. Good catch xD

Comment: Sweet ! This worked :-) Thank you !