# Numpy element-wise mean for 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to compute the element-wise mean of elements in a 1D array.

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])
>>> b = element_wise_mean(a)
>>> b
array([2., 4., 6.])
```

Is there anything that will already do this other than a simple custom function?

Comment: can you be more explicity? you have an array of 4 elements and you expect an array of 4 elements as output. what is for you element-wiseness?

Comment: For an N-element array, I expect an N-1 array to be returned as shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
>>> (a[:-1]+a[1:])/2
array([ 2.,  4.,  6.])
```

The following steps are taken:

```
>>> a[:-1]
array([1, 3, 5])
>>> a[1:]
array([3, 5, 7])
>>> a[:-1]+a[1:]
array([ 4,  8, 12])
>>> (a[:-1]+a[1:])/2
array([ 2.,  4.,  6.])
```

A more generic way would be to have a moving average filter over `N` elements (code is taken from [lapis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22621523/166605) with addition from Paul Panzer). In your case it would be averaging over two elements:

```
>>> N=2
>>> np.convolve(a, np.ones((N,))/N, mode='valid')
array([ 2.,  4.,  6.])

>>> N=3
>>> np.convolve(a, np.ones((N,))/N, mode='valid')
array([ 3.,  5.])
```

Comment: You can use `convolve` with `mode='valid'`  instead of the error prone and more difficult to read slicing.