# Why is my moving average algorithm so slow?

Tags: optimization, fortran, moving-average

I've written a Fortran function that calculates the moving average of a 1D array of numbers in a very straightforward way:

```
function moving_average(data, w)

    implicit none

    integer, intent(in) :: w
    real(8), intent(in) :: data(:)

    integer :: n, i
    real(8) :: moving_average(size(data)-w+1)

    n = w-1

    do i=1, size(data)-n
        moving_average(i) = mean(data(i:i+n))
    end do

end function
```

Where the function `mean` is defined as:

```
real(8) function mean(data)

    implicit none

    real(8), dimension(:), intent(in) :: data

    mean = sum(data)/size(data)

end function
```

When running the function `moving_average` on my laptop with a data set of 100000 numbers and a window width of 1000, it takes 0.1 seconds. However, the function `running_mean` in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27681394/6252436) using `numpy` takes only 1 ms. Why is my algorithm so much slower?

Comment: real(8) is ugly and not portable

Comment: @VladimirF What do you suggest instead? Using `selected_real_kind`?

Comment: A named constant. If it must be equal to 8, so be it, but selected_real_kind is better.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Comment: or try `iso_fortran_env`, like `use iso_fortran_env, only: real64; real(real64) :: data(:)`. There are at least the following types defined in `iso_fortran_env` of Fortran standard: `int8`, `int16`, `int32`, `int64`, `real32`, `real64`, `real128`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your algorithm is of the order O(n*m) with n the size of the moving average and m the size of the array.

Every time you compute a point in the array `moving_average`,  you do the following steps:

- extract a part of the array
- compute the sum over that slice
- divide by the constant `n`

However, `moving_average(i)` and `moving_average(i+1)` are related in the following way:

```
moving_average(i+i) = moving_average(i) + (data(i+n) - data(i-1))/n
```

When you use this, you can reduce the computational time from O(n*m) to O(m)