# Forward Propagate values while taking averages

Tags: python, pandas, math

I'm trying to figure out how to forward propagate values in Python Pandas in the following way:
Basically, let's say I have a Pandas Series (each element is a time t):

```
[5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 9, 2, 3, 1, 9, 2, 7, 5, 7, 9, 2, 3, 1]
```

I'd like each element to be lasting 4 time periods, meaning:

```
[5, 5, 5, 5, ...]
```

However, as you can see, my 5s are going to overwrite the 2, 3, 3 etc...
In my case, I'd like to keep them all but take the average of all.

In this way, this would be:

```
[5, 3.5, 3.33, 3.25, ...]
```

I've tried:

```
myList = [5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 9, 2, 3, 1, 9, 2, 7, 5, 7, 9, 2, 3, 1]
N=4
np.convolve(myList, np.ones((N,))/N, mode='valid')
```

But I get:

```
[3.25,
 3.0,
 4.75,
 4.5,
 4.5,
 3.75,
 3.75,
 3.75,
 4.75,
 5.75,
 5.25,
 7.0,
 5.75,
 5.25,
 3.75]
```

Which is not exactly what I was expecting....

Would you know how to do this?
Many thanks

Comment: You're looking for a _running average_. Check out the results in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean

Comment: I've tried myList = [5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 9, 2, 3, 1, 9, 2, 7, 5, 7, 9, 2, 3, 1]
N=4
np.convolve(myList, np.ones((N,))/N, mode='valid')
but this is not getting the same results as i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
s = pd.Series([5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 9, 2, 3, 1, 9, 2, 7, 5, 7, 9, 2, 3, 1])
s.rolling(4, min_periods=1).mean()

0     5.000000
1     3.500000
2     3.333333
3     3.250000
4     3.000000
5     4.750000
6     4.500000
7     4.500000
8     3.750000
9     3.750000
10    3.750000
11    4.750000
12    5.750000
13    5.250000
14    7.000000
15    5.750000
16    5.250000
17    3.750000
dtype: float64
```