# moving average in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, moving-average

I've tried to create a generator function which can find simple moving average of the list, but it doesn't work at all. I think the root of the problem might be in finding sum

```
def gen(lst, n):
    s = 0
    for i, _ in enumerate(lst):
        if lst[i] < n:
            s += lst[n - (n-i)]
```

my code does nothing when i play it. What should I do?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Nothing happens because you never call the generator.  We have little idea how you expect this to work, because you've used meaningless variable names and have provided no calling program or documentation.  You seem to be confused about the difference between a list and a list element.  You will need to explain your "moving average" concept, because what you implemented is something different than the usual idea.

Comment: you forgot creating loop for variable i.

Comment: Most of all, it appears that you've avoided testing any of your code until this point; you now seem to have multiple problems at once, which will make it harder to debug.  Please trace the operation with strategic `print` statements to reduce this to a single question. See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.

Comment: You never defined `i`, and you're not showing how you're calling your generator. We don't have enough information to go off of, so the answers here are going to be shots in the dark.

Comment: this will give you an idea how to create moving avg in python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13732668/6660373

Comment: Do you need your own code fixed, or do you merely need your problem solved?  If all you need is moving-average code, then this question is off-topic because you didn't look up the solution on your own.  We expect you to do such research before posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if lst[i] < n:
```

You do not define `i`

but I guess `i` is a index of `lst` so try:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(lst):
  if lst[i] < n:
    s += lst[n - (n-i)]
```

EDIT:

```
def gen(lst, n):
    if n > len(lst):
        print("Sorry can't do this")
    try:
        for i, _ in enumerate(lst[:-(n-1)]):
            s = sum(lst[i:i+n])
            yield s/n
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Sorry can't do this")
```

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't help

Comment: Can you post an example of an input and the desired output?

Comment: I updated my question, there is what I've tried to input and the thing is that there is no output

Comment: you get to yield only if lst[i] < n, in your example all are equal or bigger than n except the first (1)...

Comment: i'm sorry maybe i didn't get it right. If i write 'yield' before 'if lst[i] < n' there would be SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you trying to find the average between two adiacent numbers in your list?

Comment: in this example, yes. but if change n=3, programme must calculate average between three adiacent numbers and so on

Answer (score 0):

You may have some issues with this code snippet because you did not include some relevant variables and how they are used.

Below is an example of how you can calculate a moving average of `list_of_numbers`, given a position `p` with a period of `n`.

```
def mAverage(list_of_numbers, p, n):
    if n < p:
        return sum(list_of_numbers[p-n:p])/n
    else:
        return sum(list_of_numbers[0:p])/(p + 1)
```

Note: At the beginning of the list this function will only calculate the moving average with a period equal to the position in the list.