# Rolling mean over numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, rolling-computation

I want to go through the `list_` function within the numpy array and much like a for loop I want the mean to be calculated of every 3 numbers in the list. So the `y_mean` would be calculated with the first 3 values `457.334015,424.440002,394.795990` and then it will be calculated with the next 3 values `424.440002,394.795990,408.903992` and so on. The `y_mean` function does not work below is there a way I could fix it.

```
import numpy as np
list_= np.array([457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000])

number = 3
start = np.arange(start=1, stop=len(list_)-number, step=1)
stop = np.arange(start=number+1, stop=len(list_), step=1)
y_mean = list_[start:stop].mean()
print(y_mean)
```

Comment: @Julien I have updated the details. The `y_mean` does not go through the ranged `list_`

Comment: You have posted the same question twice, please wait for an answer for that and if you want to change something about the question, please edit that instead of starting a new post. Other people might be trying to solve your original post.

Comment: @firefireeyyy please let me know if my answer is useful :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving average or running mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.convolve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html):

```
np.convolve(list_, np.ones(3), "valid")/3
```

Comment: `np.convolve(list_, np.ones(3/3), "valid")` also works