# For and While Loop nesting to create rolling averages

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

so I have a dataframe with emotions as column headers and float scores of length 320 as the row values and I'm trying to create a loop that averages the score for every 10 scores in the series across all 4 emotions so I should have 40 averages the first 10 are for happy, next 10 for sad etc... Ideally stored as a dictionary or new dataframe with emotions as columns and average scores as rows or values.

With the loop below I get some results but nesting the loops correctly is the problem. Im sure someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

```
rolling_avgs = {}
emotions = ['happy', 'sad', 'bonding', 'leisure'] # aka my_df columns / rolling_avgs dict key values
i_i = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] # indexer
i_s = 0 # start slice indexer
i_e = 12 # end slice endexer

for i in i_i:
  while i_e <= 320:

  # dict to capture the averages as values and emotion as keys
  rolling_avg[ emotions[i] ] = np.mean(my_df[emotions[i]].iloc[i_s:i_e])


  i_s += 10
  i_e += 10
```

Comment: Why don't you use pandas's [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) function?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I had forgotten about that, thanks man.

Comment: I'd still appreciate if someone can show how to nest a for and while loop correctly for something like this anyway

Comment: Then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44797397/4727702) answer