# How to calculate centered moving mean (i.e., matlabs 'movmean') in python using numpy or scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, average

I want to create a function identical to matlabs [movmean](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmean.html) function, whereby a sliding window moves through each datapoint in a list/array, and creates a new datapoint based on the average of its neighbors (centered on the current datapoint). I have created an illustration to demonstrate what I want the function to do [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kCpL.jpg). Basically: the function creates the average of the points in the window - and shrinks near the endpoints to only include existing elements (i.e., the "shrink" option in matlabs function). In the illustration, the thicker middle bar shows the current index; and it takes the average of the current and last index of the window size is even.

I have tried to get this to work all day, but I don't seem to have the mental capacity to figure it out. I am happy to attach some code of what I have tried if you want.

EDIT: I want to clarify that, for example, np.convolve, which has been suggested as a method for moving mean, wont work in this case, since this method creates a moving average by taking the average of the current index value + the next two index values, if your window is size 3. In the function I want, I want to create the average of the index value before, the current index value and the upcoming index value, if the window is size 3.

I should also mention that I cannot look at the source code of the movmean in matlab - try yourself 'edit movmean' in matlab. You can just see the comment text, and not the source code.

Comment: without any code to see what the problem is the best we can do is suggest already done solution. In the future suggestion you include your problem, and what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Such function already exists in scipy and numpy libraries, probably should look at similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean/22621523#22621523).

Would recommend to check out the source code of the functions and compare to your implement.