# Setting a limit on the number of array elements to be cumulatively summed?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cumulative-sum

I have a length 5 array, e.g.

```
array = [1,2,6,4,3]
```

What I want is a new array cumulatively summing a maximum set number of previous values, i.e. 3:

```
return_array = [1,3,9,12,13]
```

Using numpy's 'cumsum' function seemed like a good starting point, however it appears restricted to summing the complete range of elements, giving:

```
cumsum_array = np.cumsum(array)
cumsum_array = [1,3,9,13,16]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show how you calculated the `12,13` ?

Comment: This cumsum difference answer is the one you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28884909/901925

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do this using `zip`:

```
a_ = [0] * 2 + a
list(map(sum, zip(a_, a_[1:], a_[2:])))

> [1, 3, 9, 12, 13]
```